# While Migrating a Binding to the Unified API, app is working only on iOS simulator

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

After doing "Migrating a Binding to the Unified API", app is working only on
    iOS simulator but on devices, we are getting this error message:

```
Error MT2002: Failed to resolve "System.Void
UIKit.UITableView::set_DataSource(UIKit.IUITableViewDataSource)" reference from "Xamarin.iOS, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065"
```

with the reference of the following urls and sub links, we have modified our code according to Unified API.
http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/macios/updating_ios_apps/

Our Xamarin version details:

```
Xamarin.iOS
Version: 8.4.0.43 (Business Edition)
```

Comment: Maybe some of the nuget packages (or just dll or binding projects) you are using are targeting old API?

Comment: completely removed monotouch references, anyhow it is working in iOS simulator.

Comment: when we set linker options -> Don't Link, then it is working for devices also but it is not the right solution.

Comment: I had the same issue - problem was in binding projects targeted old API.

Comment: okay,  these are my details 1. I am not using nuget packages, 2. two class libraries and one main project i am using but i have removed monotouch from all projects and referenced Xamarin.iOS. 3, SQlite.net component we are using and i have updated.  Now tell me what to do and where do i check..

Comment: Hmmm, yeah, in this case, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Please add `-v -v -v -v` to the additional mtouch arguments of the main project, and pastebin a complete (re)build log.